# How to keep and restore OS state when electricity was goes off?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I am using laptop and want to not lose my operating system running state when electricity was goes off. Of course this question can be solved by using a laptop battery or external power supply (such as UPS), but I do not have not battery and do not have a UPS.

I think that there can be something useful to solve this question? Like an application that runs at startup and periodically saves a memory snapshots to a primary storage device? So at boot I can choose if I want to restore a saved state or resume a normal boot. Is there something similar that exists for Linux systems?

Comment: Yes;  You use a laptop batter with your laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound but I have placed my laptop battery on hold to save it lifetime. I do not want to purchase another battery to increase lifetime of battery which I currently have.

Comment: @JakeGould so the main problem is that a task for a making snapshots is a very expensive task. I expected to hear something like that... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Set up a virtual machine where you'll work and take regular snapshots of the VM.

- Upon power failure, your system can simply be restored from the last snapshot, limiting data loss to at most the snapshot interval (I'd suggest somewhere between 5 and 15 minutes). Restoring the snapshot will bring you back exactly where your system was at the time it was taken. You'll probably need to write a script or add a scheduled task to instruct the hypervisor to do this automatically.
- This is much more difficult than it sounds. You'll need an extra Windows license for the virtualized instance, and your data, apps, and settings need to be migrated to the VM. Each snapshot can require a substantial amount of disk space, and older snapshots have to be merged into the main disk image. These operations require lots of disk I/O and can significantly impact your system's performance.
- Of course, the best solution would simply to use your laptop battery and have the system hibernate when the battery runs low.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looks like using a VM is the most efficient solution which can be applied for this question. But virtualization have some limitations so that is why I think about some application which I can run on host machine. Now I understand that to write an application which can solve this question makes no sense, only because this can be solved in hardware way.